# Is there a better way to write this repetitive event-declaration code in C# when implementing an interface explicitly?

Tags: c#, refactoring, events, boilerplate

I have a lot of code like the following, where I explicitly implement some events required by an interface.

```
public class IMicrowaveNotifier {
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> DoorClosed;
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> LightbulbOn;
  // ...
}

public class Microwave : IMicrowaveNotifier {
  private EventHandler<EventArgs> _doorClosed;
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> IMicrowaveNotifier.DoorClosed {
    add { lock (this) _doorClosed += value; }
    remove { lock (this) _doorClosed -= value; }
  }

  private EventHandler<EventArgs> _lightbulbOn;
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> IMicrowaveNotifier.LightbulbOn {
    add { lock (this) _lightbulbOn += value; }
    remove { lock (this) _lightbulbOn -= value; }
  }

  // ...
}
```

You can see that much of this is boilerplate. In Ruby I'd be able to do something like this:

```
class Microwave
  has_events :door_closed, :lightbulb_on, ...
end
```

Is there a similar shorter way of removing this boilerplate in C#?

---

**Update:** I left a very important part out of my example: namely, the events getting implemented are part of an interface, and I want to implement it explicitly. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier!

Comment: Offtopic, but generally using lock(this) is bad. Refer the remarks here for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: @dcp - While I agree that `lock(this)` is a bad practice, it interesting to note that the C# compiler emits this very instruction for field-like events in versions 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Microwave {
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DoorClosed;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> LightbulbOn;
}
```

This code leverages C#'s [field-like event syntax](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_17.7.1_Field-like_events):

> When compiling a field-like event, the
>   compiler automatically creates storage
>   to hold the delegate, and creates
>   accessors for the event that add or
>   remove event handlers to the delegate
>   field.

In C# 1, 2, and 3 this code will compile down to just what you have above.  In C# 4 you will get functionally equivalent code that [doesn't use explicit locks](http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx).  Either way you can use this shortcut without changing the consumers of this type.

**Update:**  Unfortunately, the C# compiler does not allow you to use field-like events for explicit interface implementation.  If you try you will get this compilation error:

> An explicit interface implementation of an event must use event accessor syntax

**Update:** It's too bad that an explicit interface implementation requires the use of event accessor syntax.  It would be kind of cool if C# added the ability to create automatically implemented field-like events like this:

```
event EventHandler<EventArgs> IAppliance.DoorClosed { add; remove; }
```

But this syntax is already wordier than the existing field-like event syntax and would only be applicable in cases where an interface member was being explicitly implemented.  The best thing I think would be if the compiler would simply allow us to do this:

```
event EventHandler<EventArgs> IAppliance.DoorClosed;
```

Comment: @Andrew: Very sorry, but I left an important piece of the puzzle out of my question. Specifically, I'm using explicit interface implementation for the events. This seems to require using `add`/`remove` directly. I made the update above.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for the update. That's pretty much the same conclusion I reached. Bummer! Is there any way that extension methods would help here?

Comment: So it seems the answer to your question is no: C# will not allow you to avoid the repetition.

Comment: @Damien - Sorry dude!  I think your only option is to manually create the backing fields and the `add` and `remove` accessors. It's too bad really - perhaps C# 5 will give us something like this:  `event EventHandler<EventArgs> IAppliance.DoorClosed { add; remove; }`

Comment: A very strange restriction, IMO, as you can implement properties in interfaces by meant of automatic properties. I'd say open a Connect suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `Lock` does as I am kind of new, but you can connect all of the controls or whatever is calling those events to only one event. In that event just do a `if` statement to check who is sending it.

It would look much neater I would think, but still require a some amount of work I guess.

Comment: His question was poorly titled. His issue is with the verbosity of the code, not the events firing frequently. FWIW, I had expected to see a question to which this would have been an answer.

Comment: @Adam, @Dinoo: I've edited the title. Hopefully this is less confusing now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Write a code snippet for it and use a shortcut.  Just like when you use if, for, foreach{tab}{tab}.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippets as suggested by gbogumil will save some time. Alternately, if there's a specific interface you find yourself implementing regularly that requires this, is it possible for you to create an abstract base class?